# Unmarshalling JAX-RS response xml (content-type: text/xml) with formatting errors

Tags: spring, jax-rs, content-type, unmarshalling

The JAX-RS web service I'm calling is throwing xml content as text/html content type. On my side, I need to read the xml, and convert it to Java object.

The problem is: the response xml isn't formatted right and has newline characters in wrong places, such as - there are several newline characters before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` . This is causing problems trying to unmarshall it.

Is there a way I can unmarshall the response xml string though it has formatting problems?

Thanks in advance.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
MyClass myObj = (MyClass) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inputStream);
```

Comment: Could you show your code relating to this matter?

Comment: Are there also formatting problems inside? or just before <?xml..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the provider to send the response in xml/application format. However, as a way out, an option that I found is to save the content as a file, and then again retrieve content from the file.

Answer (score 0):

How about trimming the content before unmarshalling:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; 
import org.apache.commons.lang.CharEncoding;

MyClass myObj = MyClass.class.cast(
  context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
    IOUtils.toInputStream(
      IOUtils.toString(
        InputStream.class.cast(response.getEntity().getContent()),
        CharEncoding.UTF_8
      ).trim(),
      CharEncoding.UTF_8
    )
  )
);
```